# How can I download a string from a URL in a C++Builder VCL application?

Tags: c++, string, c++builder, vcl, downloadstring

I want to download a string from a URL that would essentially look like this:

- https://website.com/File.txt

In C# WinForms, I know I can do this:

```
using System.Net;
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string str = client.DownloadString("https://website.com/file.txt");
```

And the string would be stored in `str`. I want to do exactly that in a C++ VCL application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of HTTP libraries that are available for C++Builder.  It even comes with 2 pre-installed:

Indy's `TIdHTTP` component

```
#include <IdHTTP.hpp>

TIdHTTP *client = new TIdHTTP();
String str = client->Get(_D("https://website.com/file.txt"));
delete client;
```

Embarcadero's [`THTTPClient`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Net.HttpClient.THTTPClient) component:

```
#include <System.Net.HttpClient.hpp>

THTTPClient *client = THTTPClient::Create();
String str = client->Get(_D("https://website.com/file.txt"))->ContentAsString();
delete client;
```